# Magento registration not working

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, onepage-checkout

After updating several patches on the Magento environment I've run into a bug that I cannot get solved. When logging into my account and setting up a order, everything works fine. Now I am getting an error on the register an account page:

```
Cannot save the customer.
```

I cannot find where the problem is coming from and I've been looking around for the bug on here for a while, no solutions. What is going wrong and where is it bugging? The error im getting when setting up a message after the PHP code is:

```
Cannot save the customer.Invalid method Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::cleanPasswordsValidationData(Array ( ) )
```

What does this mean and where am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `cleanPasswordsValidationData()` method was introduced in Magento 1.9.1.0 and thus, on your installation (Magento 1.9.0.1), that method cannot be found.

Most of the time the problem is caused by custom modules interacting with the Customer registration/login (like AJAX Login/Registration or One Step Checkout) where the code of the extension uses that function without checking the Magento version first.

My recommendation is to look for calls to that function `cleanPasswordsValidationData()` in your website code and find the extension causing the problem.

Once you find the line causing the issue you can add the following condition around it to avoid the problem:

```
if (version_compare(Mage::getVersion(),"1.9.1.0",">="))
{
    // Only from 1.9.1.0
    $customer->cleanPasswordsValidationData();
}
```

Comment: Where do I look for the calls for this function? I've been looking around all the code..

Comment: You can use the following UNIX command on your root folder via SSH: `grep -r cleanPasswordsValidationData .` it will give you the list of files where that function is written.

Comment: I found 3 times this line, `cleanPasswordsValidationData();` in AccountController.php but cannot place it where it is bugging. 

`if (empty($errors)) {
                $customer->cleanPasswordsValidationData();
                $customer->save();
                $this->_dispatchRegisterSuccess($customer);
                $this->_successProcessRegistration($customer);
                return;`

This would be the most logical piece where to put it right?

Comment: Which AccountController.php are you talking about ? Because if it's the `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers` that function should not be there as you stated you were running 1.9.0.1 but yeah that's the place to put the code I pasted yeah

Comment: `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers` is the location where it is at. I am running 1.9.0.1 but have several patches installed.

Comment: Well one of the patch must have added that call. Use my piece of code to fix the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36263/discussion-between-axel-dekker-and-digital-pianism).